# How does one perform a logical AND on an array of booleans in javscript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

#### Scenario and Question

Say you have an array of booleans in javascript:

```
[true, false, true, true, false]
```

What's the best practice for performing a logical 'AND' operation on all of these values so that the above example would become:

```
false
```

In other words, what's the best practice for AND'ing all of these values together?

---

#### My solution

The best/cleanest way I thought of is using the reduce function like so:

```js
const array1 = [true, false, true, true];

const initialValue = array1[0];
const array1And = array1.reduce(
  (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue && currentValue,
  initialValue
);

console.log(array1And); //false
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve the same?

Comment: `Array.every()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for AND or the [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for OR

```js
const array1 = [true, false, true, true];

const or = array1.some(Boolean);
const and = array1.every(Boolean);

console.log({ or, and });
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful. I don't use javascript often - wasn't aware of `.some` and `.every`

Comment: Nice to see the mention of `some` as well.

Comment: This is a really nice code snippet. I think it is useful to point out though that in this case the `Boolean` argument passed to `some()` and `every()` basically just acts as identify function. Another way to achieve this would be to use `array1.some( b => b )`.

Comment: @etchesketch exactly right.